# How to obtain a 3d vector between two 3d vectors with a maximum angle?

Tags: math, vector, 3d

Let's say I have a vector v1=(0,0,1), a vector v2=(1,0,0) and a maximum angle of 20 degrees, how do I obtain a vector that is between these two vectors, in the 2d plane that these two vectors are forming, but is rotated 20 degrees from the first one(v1) ? (Assuming that there are more than 20 degrees from v1 and v2)

Comment: Do you know how to take a cross product? Do you know how to rotate one vector about another by a given angle?

Answer (score 0):

Approach w/o matrices:

Any vector that lies in that plane can be expressed in form:

```
v3 = x v1 + y v2
```

So, we need to find a and b. And btw, vectors may have less than 20 degrees between them. 
Assuming that all vectors are normalized.

```
v3 v1 = cosA = x + y v1 v2
|v3| = 1 = x2 + y2 + x y v1 v2
```

In your particular case the solution of these equations is:

```
x = cosA, y = sqrt(1 - cos2(A))
v3 = cosA v1 + sqrt(1 - cos2(A)) v2
```

In general case you need to solve the following equations:

```
x + Ay + B = 0
x2 + y2 + Axy + C = 0
```

where

```
A = v1 v2, B = - cosA, C = -1
```

If you have troubles solving it, I will give you some tips in comments.